# Shibboleth Metadata Files based connectivity to IDP

Tags: .net, single-sign-on, shibboleth

I am connecting WGU(Western Governors University) idp with our Shibboleth service provider. We don't have idp metadata url but have idp metadata file.

How to connect to idp from our service provider.

Thanks,

Pradeep Kumar

Answer (score 0):

Your Identity Provider (IdP) will provide either a metadata file or a link to that metadata file. In that file will be defined endpoints that tell your SP (Service Provider) where to send users to authenticate. You tell your Shibboleth SP where this metadata file is via the `<MetadataProvider>` section in the file `shibboleth2.xml`.  You will probably also have to give *your* metadata to your IdP.

Comment: I set the below MetadataProvider  tag in Shibboleth.xml file. In the SessionInitator tag  EntityID shound be an Url. But identityID  value is "edu.wgu" in idp metadata file they have provided. if set this entityID value in the SessionInitator  tag then it's throwing an error "not able to  reach on idetitymetadata(edu.wgu)"


<MetadataProvider id="ShibbolethMetadata1" type="FilesystemMetadataProvider" metadataFile="C:/opt/shibboleth-sp/WGU-ComplioRev2-2017-06-20metadata.xml"  />

Comment: Firstly, entity IDs are usually URLs but they don't have to be: they serve merely as an identifier. Secondly, in your question "How to proceed with file based metadata" which metadata are you referring to: yours or the IdPs.